# multiple class attributes validation with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class with 3 attributes: game_finished, slots_selected and winner, and I want to check the three at the same time

this way: if slots_selected has a value less than 9 and the winner is equal to 0 and game_finished is false, the test should pass.

How can I validate that condition with RSpec?

I'd tried this way:

```
it 'some description' do
    game = Game.new

    expect([game.game_finished, game.winner, game.slots_selected).to eq([false, 0, 8])
end
```

The problem here is that the slots_selected is a fixed number, and I should test it against any number less than 9

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to have seperate expects for each object

```
expect(game.game_finished).to eq(false) 
expect(game.winner).to eq(0)
expect(game.slots_selected < 9).to be(true)
```

But it seems that you have confused logic here.  TDD should help you write better code.  Isolate the business logic into the boolean values needed to answer a true or false type question. But You have not made it clear what the rules to your logic should be.  Here's perhaps a better example of how you might do this:

```
let(:game) { Game.new }

it 'checks that game has not finished yet' do
   expect(game.finished?).to be false
end

it 'checks that game has not sarted yet' do
   expect(game.started?).to be false
end

it 'starts games less than 9 slots' do
  expect(game.slots_selected < 9).to be(true)
end
```

The idea is you should be testing the output or results of methods. Write the specs first, then get them to pass.